# Is this if statement well expressed?

Tags: python, function

I tried to optimize an if statement in one single line and it seems to work properly in my shell but when I test it return nothing. Do you see somethind strange?. The goal of this function is replace the if statement with a single.  return statement, and thats what I did.

This is the original function:

```
def same_length(L1, L2):
    '''(list, list) -> bool

    Return True if and only if L1 and L2 contain the same number of elements.
    '''

    if len(L1) == len(L2):
       return True
    else:
       return False
```

And this is my optimization:

```
return True if len(L1) == len(L2) else False # Do you see something strange here?
```

Is this correct?

Comment: why not just `return len(L1) == len(L2)` This is already a boolean expression resulting with True or False :) just return it

Comment: If you have some code where this returns nothing, by all means include it in your question so people can look at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct, but you do not have to make it so complicated. It is equivalent to:

```
return len(L1) == len(L2)
```

There is no need to use an `if`-statement here: the result of `len(L1) == len(L2)` is already a boolean. If that boolean is `True` you return `True` and the same for `False`. Simply returning the outcome of the test is equivalent (and more efficient).